# Socket programming in android - Reading bytes from input stream is very slow over Wifi

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin, serversocket

I am using Sockets for transferring data over Wifi in my android app, I have set the Buffer size to around 10MB and here is my code for sending data.

```kotlin
// Sending data from a file in chunks, PREFERRED_CHUNK_SIZE is [1024 * 1024 * 10]

var fileSize = fileList[index].totalSize
val buffer = ByteArray(SocketConstants.PREFERRED_CHUNK_SIZE)
var length: Int
do {
    length = stream.read(buffer, 0, min(buffer.size, fileSize))
    bos.write(buffer, 0, length)
    fileSize -= length
} while (fileSize != 0)
 stream.close()
```

I am reusing the same code for multiple file transfer, the condition filesize != 0 makes sure I read only that much bytes for a single file and thus I have used that min function lets say I want to send 36 MB it is sent as 10(10485760 bytes), 10(10485760 bytes), 10(10,485,760 bytes), 6.

Below is my code for receiver:

```kotlin
        var fileSize = file.totalSize
        var current: Int
        var offset = 0
        val byteArray = ByteArray(SocketConstants.PREFERRED_CHUNK_SIZE)
        val bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(inputStream)
        do {
            current = bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray, 0, min(byteArray.size, fileSize))
//            outputStream.write(byteArray, 0, current)  To ignore file write for now
            fileSize -= current
            offset += current
            println("Length: $current")
            file.bytesDownloaded = offset
            updateList(offset)
        } while (fileSize != 0)
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
```

When reading I am getting really small chunks of bytes, 1358, 1358, 1358, 1358, 1358.

This is really slow, I don't understand what is causing inputStream.read() such small reads.

I have already set the sender and receiver buffer size for SocketServer and Socket instance. But there was no difference in the results

Comment: That buffer is ridicuously big. 8192 should be enough.

Comment: It is tcp/ip that determines the chunck size.

Comment: Are you transferring between two Android devices?

Comment: Yes, I am transferring between two Android devices. Do you think the buffer is causing  it to slow?

Comment: Why is the receiver declaring such a large buffer? If you are transferring a file then save the received bytes directly to disk instead of gathering them in memory.

Comment: `, 1358, 1358, 1358, 1358, 1358.

This is really slow` Slow? They are small chuncks yes. But slow? Slow has to do with time. With speed.

Comment: I will reduce the buffer and try it. Also, I referred a lot of websites to get to this implementation. Can you tell me how to directly write to the file? or any references. Thanks

Comment: You may have a look at the MTU (maximum transmission unit) for your Wifi connection. - Also you may try using this code (if applicable) in a "normal" Java program and transmit the data over Wifi and also Ethernet to see if there's any difference.

Comment: Tried multiple sharing applications, they are taking around 20 seconds to transfer a 36 MB file. The code I have written is taking 3-4 minutes

Comment: `outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()` ? We dont see you writing to that stream. So what is going on?

Comment: I am writing, I have just commented the file write for simplicity. Forgot to comment out outputstream.flush and close

Comment: If you already write to a file then why did you ask how to do it?

Comment: I thought there is some other way, without using the buffer byte array

Comment: `var fileSize = file.totalSize` What is file? How did you get to know the size of the receiving data?

Comment: You need a receiving buffer of say 8192 and then write the bytes in the buffer directly to file.

Comment: I have sent the filesize and filename ahead of filetransfer in same output stream using write and readUTF

Comment: I am getting 0.086192 Mbps even after reducing the buffer

Answer (score 0):

After looking for a solution for few days and trying multiple ways to increase the speed when read is called on inputstream I finally discovered the solution.

Thanks Gerd in comments who kind of helped me start thinking about the strength of a Wifi connection.

What I found was, if you connect to wifi using Android Wifi Manager, the connection established is a slow connection and you wouldn't even see in the task bar if you are connected to an actual wifi.

To overcome it, I manually connected to hotspot using Wifi settings in the mobile and that has better speed.